# New to QA, what is this test technique called?

Tags: manual-testing, testcase

Entry level QA. Have a question. I was tasked today to compare old tests to our current build and compose a document containing all of the differences between what the test steps expected result versus current result. Essentially cross referencing and documenting minor changes. What would this process be called? I understand that I was likely tasked to do this to get me familiarized with manual testing and it may not have any importance at all but I am interested if there's a technical term for it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So you *executed* regression tests and *reported* their *actual* and *expected* results?

Comment: It is actually not clear to me if this is a regression test or not. The OP could be updating the test cases because the Expected Result no longer matches the desired behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tests are of a released project, then this process may have been done to understand the changes between how the application was planned initially and how it turned out after several improvements in requirements and developing different variants.

If the tests are of previous phase, then the its is manual regression testing, used to check if bugs are introduced in previously verified modules, due to integration of new modules to older ones.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this would be called [regression testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tags/regression-testing/info).

Comment: Please write the description why you believe it is regression testing.

Comment: While your answer is correct, it would be better if you were to edit your answer to expand on the nature of regression testing and why the OP has been tasked with performing it. The help center has more information on what makes a good answer (https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I believe my answer was sufficient. The OP asked what the process they were doing was called and I provided the answer. I don't see any other question from them regarding the things you mention. Of course, they can always ask for clarification or more information in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as **Regression Testing** since while developing the new features or doing [refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) of existing code the changes might impact the existing features and hence might break them down (this is called a [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_regression)).

This why you were asked to run existing "old" tests against new build. To make sure the new code changes didn't impact the existing "old" features.

Answer (score 0):

Old test cases are run against current build to verify that new changes did not affect the old features.  This is called as Regression testing.

The outcome of the regression testing might result in updating old test cases that does not match with the current build.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of Regression Testing since there would be some features that might not have changed. Additionally it is refactoring where the Expected have been changed for some tests.

Testers in leading [qa testing services](https://www.qasource.com/) companies follow this approach. This process is essential in keeping the document up-to-date, so that new/existing engineers working on the project don't face any difficulty in understanding the product.